# How to query for non A-Z entries?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a table with a field `title`. I currently query by letter as follows:

```
Group.where("title like ?", "#{@letter}%")
```

This works great for `a-z`.

What can I pass to `@letter` to get all rows that do not start with `a-z`? Entries that start with '1', or '500' or some other non `a-z` character for example?

Comment: Tried this w/o luck: .where("title ~* ?", "[^a-z]%")

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid suggestion since you ask for what to pass to @letter but you could change a little the query using "title NOT LIKE ?". Of course I don't know your code and I don't know if you _have to_ use exactly this query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [regular expression match](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE) for that in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  title ~ E'^\\w.*';
```

\w being the [class shorthand](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) for `[[:alnum:]_]`. Note that this only includes digits and the underscore `_`.
Or:

```
title ~ E'^[^a-zA-Z].*'
```

.. to match all characters except `a-z` and `A-Z` at the first position.

You cannot do that easily with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this will work: [^a-z]

I tested it on my own temp table and it worked fine for me:

```
select * from #test where test like '[^a-z]%'
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it returns no results... In the rails logs I see the sql where clause as follows: WHERE (title like '[^a-z]%')

Comment: Hrmmm, maybe because it is postgresql and I tested on MSSQL? Otherwise, this exact like statement works for me. I will be curious what does work

Comment: -1 This answer is wrong. You cannot mix POSIX regular expressions with the LIKE operator in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: help me understand: `[^a-z]` is valid POSIX, right? So are you saying that cannot be 'mixed' with the `%` wildcard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Yes, the `LIKE` operator has a very limited set of meta-characters. For Posix regular expression matches you need to use the `~` operator. It's all laid out [here in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html). I recently posted an [extensive answer concerning pattern matching on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10694/3684).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I geddit, thnx.